# How to constrain the range of a plot of a function to satisfy an inequality?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, piecewise

Given the function `f[x_] := x^2`, how can I plot `f[x]` over the range where `f[x] >= 10` and `x ∈ [-5 to 5]` without solving the inequality `f[x] >= 10`?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? f[x_]:=x^2; 
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y}, f[x] >= 10]]

Answer (score 6):

Here are some ways:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> (#^2 >= 10 &)]
Plot[x^2 Boole[x^2 >= 10], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 >= 10}}], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 >= 10}, {10, True}}], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 25}]
```

Note the `Piecewise` examples join the discontinuities and in the last example I make it continuous but no differentiable at $x=\pm \sqrt{10}$.